# Como apresentar uma sequencia de resultados

Tags: javascript

Olá, eu criei um gerador de números aleatórios com o seguinte script:

```
<input type="number" name="minimum" id="minimum">

<input type="number" name="maximum" id="maximum">

<button class="aazul" onclick="result()">Generate</button>
<div class="card" id="resultz"></div>

<script>
    function result(){
  const min = document.getElementById("minimum").value;
  const max = document.getElementById("maximum").value;

  let sort = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(max))

  while(sort<min){

    sort = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(max));
  }

  document.getElementById("resultz").innerHTML=sort;
}
    </script>
```

Mas ele gera um número e quando clica no botão Generate novamente gera outro numero (como já esperado). Eu gostaria de salvar uma lista de 6 números gerados como um histórico isso seria possível ou alguém poderia de indicar como fazer isso?

Answer (score -1):

Eu primeiro reavaliaria a função para ser mais precisa com o número gerado, ao invés de ficar num laço de repetição até conseguir gerar um número maior que o mínimo:

```
function result() {
  const min = Number(document.getElementById("minimum").value);
  const max = Number(document.getElementById("maximum").value);
  const range = max - min + 1;
  const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * range + min);

  document.getElementById("resultz").innerHTML = number;
}
```

Agora para guardar os últimos números gerados é só manter um array com esses números. Use *Array.push* para adicionar um valor, e *Array.slice* para remover uma quantidade de items desse array:

```
let results = [];

function result() {
  const min = Number(document.getElementById("minimum").value);
  const max = Number(document.getElementById("maximum").value);
  const range = max - min + 1;
  const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * range + min);

  results.push(number);
  if (result.length > 6) results = results.slice(1);

  document.getElementById("resultz").innerHTML = number;
}
```

Dessa forma os resultados anteriores ficaram gravados na variável *results*.

Comment: Em Amigo desculpe pela insistência. Como eu poderia deixar esses 6 resultados na pagina até atualiza-la? Queria criar uma sequencia com os 6 ultimas números gerados.